# USB Networking via a Huawei 3G device EC5805 MIFI

Tags: linux, usb, mifi

I want to connect my MiFi through the available USB connection that I enjoy in Windows, OSX 10.5, and Mint.

So far, all YDL 6.1 has done is laugh at my attempts to use the USB option in `netman`.

I did have the device recognized in `fileman`, and the drive and optional Micro-SD slot both show.

When I go to activate the interface, it says something about a package named usb-networking or some such not being installed.

I cannot locate the package on the CD, and have no other way to connect to the Internet. I haven't found anything online in several days of searching either.

Any help is appreciated.